# Why does my rectangular shape not show up in my plotly.js scatter chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly.js

I posted this question over at the plotly community forum here: https://community.plotly.com/t/why-does-my-rectangular-shape-not-show-on-my-chart/77970. I'm posting it here as well to get more responses.

I'm trying to add a rectangular shape to my chart but it's not showing up.

Here is the code by which I add the rectangle:

```
layout.shapes = _.map(regions, function(region) {
    return {
        type: 'rect',
        xref: 'x',
        yref: 'paper',
        y0: 0,
        y1: 1,
        x0: region.start, // 8/13/2023 12:01:00 AM
        x1: region.end,   // 8/15/2023 12:01:00 AM
        fillcolor: '#d3d3d3',
        opacity: 1.0,
        line: {
            width: 3
        }
    };
});
```

Here's the series of events that need to occur.

1. starting with the chart (a scatter plot):

[image]

2. select a point with the lasso tool:

[image]

3. delete the point:

[image]

4. draw the rectangular region:

[image]

It's 4) that's failing to occur. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think the error is in the code you posted, it seems to work as expected, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scwkfe56/). And the only point where the problem may come from (in the absence of console errors) is the value of `regions` which I'd guess is not what you expect it is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction kikon. The values of regions were as I expected except they weren't date objects. As soon as I wrapped the x0 and x1 values like so: `x0: new Date(region.start)` and `x1: new Date(region.end)` it worked. However, the rectangle is a few pixels off from the points themselves even though they share exactly the same dates. I will post another question and link to it from here. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962106/why-is-the-position-of-my-ractangular-shape-off-by-a-few-pixels-along-the-x-axis

Comment: In my example the dates were just strings, but `Date.parse` compatible.