# Why is the position of my ractangular shape off by a few pixels along the x axis in my Plotly.js scatter chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly.js

This is a follow up question to a previous question: [Why does my rectangular shape not show up in my plotly.js scatter chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76957236/why-does-my-rectangular-shape-not-show-up-in-my-plotly-js-scatter-chart).

At the link above, you will read about the issue I had with making a ractangular shape show up in my Plotly.js scatter plot. Kikon was kind enough to lead me in the right direction and resolve the issue. The rectangle now appears in my chart:

[image]

But as you can see, it is a bit off from the gap in the lines themselves. That is to say, the left edge of the rectangle should be perfectly align with the points at Aug 14 and the right edge with the points at Aug 16.

The dates given to the rectangle for the x0 and x1 values are taken directly from the points themselves. They are `8/14/2023 12:01:00 AM` and `8/16/2023 12:01:00 AM` which are exactly the date values of the points themselves. So why is it not aligned with them?

Here is my layout:

```
{
   "title":{
      "text":"Time Series",
      "font":{
         "color":"#3dcd58",
         "family":"Nunito-Regular",
         "size":18
      },
      "xanchor":"left",
      "x":0
   },
   "font":{
      "color":"#333",
      "family":"Nunito-Regular"
   },
   "dragmode":"lasso",
   "autosize":false,
   "width":425,
   "height":400,
   "margin":{
      "l":20,
      "r":15,
      "b":25,
      "t":30
   },
   "plot_bgcolor":"#ffffff",
   "showlegend":true,
   "legend":{
      "x":0,
      "bgcolor":"rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"
   },
   "yaxis":{
      "showticklabels":false
   },
   "yaxis2":{
      "showticklabels":false,
      "overlaying":"y"
   },
   "yaxis3":{
      "showticklabels":false,
      "overlaying":"y"
   },
   "shapes":[
      {
         "type":"rect",
         "xref":"x",
         "yref":"paper",
         "y0":0,
         "y1":1,
         "x0":"2023-08-14T06:01:00.000Z",
         "x1":"2023-08-16T06:01:00.000Z",
         "fillcolor":"#d3d3d3",
         "opacity":0.3,
         "line":{
            "width":0
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

And here is the data:

```
[
   {
      "type":"scatter",
      "x":[
         "2023-08-13T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-14T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-15T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-16T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-17T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-18T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-19T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-20T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-21T06:01:00.000Z"
      ],
      "y":[
         19.328703703703702,
         20.833333333333332,
         null,
         20.208333333333332,
         18.75,
         21.34259259259259,
         23.125,
         22.01388888888889,
         21.25
      ],
      "name":"°C",
      "marker":{
         "color":"red",
         "size":3,
         "opacity":[
            1,
            1,
            0.3,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1
         ]
      },
      "connectgaps":false,
      "measurementGroupId":18
   },
   {
      "type":"scatter",
      "x":[
         "2023-08-13T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-14T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-15T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-16T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-17T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-18T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-19T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-20T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-21T06:01:00.000Z"
      ],
      "y":[
         14,
         19,
         null,
         382.99,
         589.0400000000002,
         568,
         190.00000000000003,
         null,
         null
      ],
      "name":"m3",
      "marker":{
         "color":"blue",
         "size":3,
         "opacity":[
            1,
            1,
            0.3,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1
         ]
      },
      "yaxis":"y2",
      "connectgaps":false,
      "measurementGroupId":10
   },
   {
      "type":"scatter",
      "x":[
         "2023-08-13T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-14T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-15T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-16T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-17T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-18T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-19T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-20T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-21T06:01:00.000Z"
      ],
      "y":[
         10841.929999999998,
         10649.020000000004,
         null,
         12686.010000000004,
         15261.989999999998,
         14080.979999999998,
         9714.98,
         null,
         null
      ],
      "name":"kWh",
      "marker":{
         "color":"black",
         "size":3,
         "opacity":[
            1,
            1,
            0.3,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1
         ]
      },
      "yaxis":"y3",
      "connectgaps":false,
      "measurementGroupId":2
   }
]
```

Is there anything I can do to the layout to adjust the x-axis position of the rectangle?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, I don't get any issues with your data - seems a perfect match - can you please look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efqw6sr4/) and let me know if you see a shift

Comment: I see the difference. You're hard coding the x0 and x1 values with the following format: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000z`. I'm setting them with `new Date(region.start)` and `new Date(region.end)` which, when I hover over it, gives me `Sat Aug 05 2023 00:01:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) {}` and `Sat Aug 07 2023 00:01:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) {}`. However, when I `console.log(JSON.stringify(layout.shapes))` I see the format you used. When I hard code the values like you did, the gap disappears. Why would the formatting matter? Could it be a timezone issue?

Comment: By the way, `region.start` and `region.end` are unix timestamps, `1691215260000` and `1691388060000` respectively.

Comment: I just took the code from your post - it was you who gave `x0` and `x1` as strings in the code above. I think that the shift of the rectangle is indeed most likely a time zone issue. You have to take care that both the scatter plots and the layout rectangle are formatted the same way - either both UTC or both in the user's time zone.  Timestamps are consistent, that is `Date.prototype.valueOf` returns the same timestamp for two dates in different timezones that correspond to the same actual moment. If it still doesn't work, please post a link to a fiddle that actually exhibits the issue.

Comment: Thanks kikon. With your help, I was able to resolve the issue.